# Reading Array Response From API Call using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I am using thenextleg to generate images. I can successfully get the data response that I need, but I am having trouble accessing the array element `imageUrls` in the returned data array.

Pasting the API response below:

```
COMPLETED IMAGE DATA 
Array (
   [progress] => 100 
   [response] => Array 
   (
      [accountId] => dvfdfbf';gkdf'gk 
      [createdAt] => 2023-10-31T13:21:11.306Z 
      [originatingMessageId] => 0Wmr62453OSjdkbG9KWt
      [buttons] => Array
      (
         [0] => U1
         [1] => U2
         [2] => U3
         [3] => U4
         [4] => 
         [5] => V1
         [6] => V2
         [7] => V3
         [8] => V4
      )
      [imageUrl] => https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/1154420052616019998/1168902491887374336/jon709_49338_dog_992a3693-9d9a-4321-9b45-a675b393263c.png?ex=65537447&is=6540ff47&hm=85c038ca483250500d8c1e2672111bb1583d0b1bb772fbc161057ab2202dd447&
      [imageUrls] => Array
      (
         [0] => https://cdn.midjourney.com/992a3693-9d9a-4321-9b45-a675b393263c/0_0.png
         [1] => https://cdn.midjourney.com/992a3693-9d9a-4321-9b45-a675b393263c/0_1.png
         [2] => https://cdn.midjourney.com/992a3693-9d9a-4321-9b45-a675b393263c/0_2.png
         [3] => https://cdn.midjourney.com/992a3693-9d9a-4321-9b45-a675b393263c/0_3.png
      )
      [responseAt] => 2023-10-31T13:21:12.009Z
      [description] =>
      [type] => imagine
      [content] => dog
      [buttonMessageId] => nD9LIfo7cheaMgSUCnQ1
   )
)
```

I have tried using `$completedImageData[imageUrls][$i];`

Where `$i` would be a value from 0-3.

How does one access it?

I have tried many different code variations but still cannot seem to access the URLs that I need.

Comment: Looks like you missed the `response` part. Could you please use `var_export()` to dump your array, easier to read and copy/paste ready

Comment: Thank-you! I was missing the response part.